# Azure Devops: for each loop over AzureKeyVault@2 output

Tags: azure-devops, azure-keyvault

I have an Azure Keyvault with many secrets and I want to create Kubernetes secrets for ALL items.

```yaml
jobs:
  - job: getAndSetKeys
    steps:
      - task: AzureKeyVault@2
        inputs:
          connectedServiceName: myAzureConnection
          keyVaultName: myKeyVaultName
          secretsFilter: "*"
          runAsPreJob: true
      - ${{ each secret in getAndSetKeys.output}}: ##???
        - task: Kubernetes@1
          inputs:
            namespace: clusterNameSpace
            connectionType: Kubernetes Service Connection
            kubernetesServiceEndpoint: myServiceConnection
            secretType: generic
            secretArguments: --from-literal=KEY=$(secret.value)
            secretName: $(secret.name)
```

The `AzureKeyVault@2` sets environmental variables, is there any way to refer to the task output?

Comment: Why not implement a Kubernetes keyvault provider? i.e. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/csi-secrets-store-driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, for-each loops can only be applied on parameters, not on outputs from previous jobs since those could not be compiled at time of pipeline start.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#each-keyword

You'll probably need to create a custom script and do a loop in there and apply your logic.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, but had to place all KeyVault secrets in one secret.

First task get all keys and values from the KeyVault and writes them to a file.
Second step creates the secret from this env file:

```yaml
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(armServiceConnection)
    scriptType: bash
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
      for secretName in $(az keyvault secret list --vault-name $(vaultName) | jq -r '.[].name'); do
          secretValue=`az keyvault secret show --vault-name $(vaultName) --name ${secretName} | jq '.value'`
          echo "${secretName}=${secretValue}" >> kv-secrets.txt
      done
- task: Kubernetes@1
  displayName: Create Kubernetes secret
  inputs:
    namespace: $(clusterNameSpace)
    connectionType: Kubernetes Service Connection
    kubernetesServiceEndpoint: $(serviceConnection)
    secretType: generic
    secretArguments: --from-env-file=kv-secrets.txt
    secretName: joost-test-test
```

This is the custom-script that @siltent is talking about. I will accept his answer since that is an actual answer to the initial problem.